# Add Results of ParallelMap in Parallel

Tags: memory, parallelization

I'm new to coding in parallel, but I really could use it. I need a command to call a function on each element in a huge list, and then add them all up. Currently I use something like this:

```
Apply[Plus, ParallelMap[f,Huge_List]]
```

This is faster than just using `Map`, but it quickly is maxing out my computer's memory. Since each evaluation on the huge list is independent and since the results are simply added, I was wondering if there was a way to get *Mathematica* to evaluate the sum as it is evaluating the mapping. The idea is for *Mathematica* to not have to keep the entire result of `ParallelMap` in memory and to instead just keep the running total as it is evaluating the mapping. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Look up `ParallelCombine`.  Or break the huge list into parts of appropriate size, then let each subkernel first map `f` onto a part, then sum it, then return only the result of the summation.  Finally sum the partial totals.

Comment: Just saw this http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/, which I think could also be useful for you. It's an out of core processing library, meaning you can process datasets larger than your physical memory. It's in Python though, but luckily for me comments can't be downvoted:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ParallelCombine` solution.

```
hugeList = Range[0, 2*10^4];
f[x_] := x

ParallelCombine[Total[Map[f, #, 1]] &, hugeList, Total[{#}] &]
(* 38503 *)
```

Chunks of `hugeList` will be handed to `Total[Map[f, #, 1]] &` in parallel. This `Total` first `Map`s `f` onto each element of the list handed to it (a chunk of `hugeList`) thereby giving a total for the chunk and not keeping the summands. The combine function `Total[{#}] &` takes all these *chunk* summands and sums them.

Answer (score 1):

`ParallelSum` will get you some memory savings. I get a successful evaluation of the following:

```
In[1]:= hugeList = Range[0, 6*10^3];
        MemoryConstrained[
          Apply[Plus, ParallelMap[N[Pi, 50]^#/#! &, hugeList]] - N[Pi, 50],
          2^20
        ]
Out[1]= 19.999099979189475767266442984669044496068936843225
```

But, taking the range up to 7e3 exceeds the 1MB constraint. However, I can go up to 2e4 using `ParallelSum`:

```
In[1]:= hugeList = Range[0, 2*10^4];
        MemoryConstrained[
          ParallelSum[N[Pi, 50]^k/k!, {k, hugeList}] - N[Pi, 50],
          2^20
        ]
Out[1]= 19.999099979189475767266442984669044496068936843225
```

Unfortunately, [the approximation](http://www.xkcd.com/217/) to 20 doesn't get any better :)

If `ParallelCombine` got a better solution, perhaps you could explain in an answer.